# OpenCV with CodeBlocks IDE

Tags: opencv, codeblocks

[image]

I am new to openCV(version 2.4.13.2) and using codeblocks IDE 16.01. I have linked all the packages and I don't have the packages mentioned in th error. What should I do to run the program?

Comment: Those aren't OpenCV-related packages, so somewhere in your library/linker settings you have them requested even though you don't have them.

Comment: @Alexander Reynolds you are correct though I have not linked them but they are appearing in the error. How should I remove the packages ?